# Does anyone remember a point and click game where you play as a kid, and a space object crashes into your house?

Tags: story-identification, video-games, webcomics

So I found this game some time in the last decade, probably at least 5 years ago. It was played using your browser, on the creator's website.  It was almost more of an interactive comic than a game.

All I remember about the game is that you are some random kid doing random things in your room at the beginning. The random things are stuff like texting your friend and moving things around. Your dad gets home but you don't want him to see you so you put a box on your head to sneak downstairs. At some point a spaceship or satellite crashes into your house. I don't remember much after that, but it had a weird vibe.

I think the guy kept publishing more and more of the story over several years.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds a lot like the first Act of [Homestuck](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/).

The 'random kid' would be the main character of Homestuck, John Egbert, and a lot of the first act does involve him doing random things before the main plot gets underway. John texting his friends (in the form of 'Pesterlogs', in Homestuck parlance) forms a crucial part of the story going forward: almost all character interaction in the webcomic occurs via pesterlogs. Your use of second person in the question is also a good indicator as Homestuck is written in second-person.

The interactive bits aren't universal but there is one notable sequence in the first act where John needs to go downstairs to pick up a video game, Sburb, that he's bought. As you said, he doesn't want to meet his father. His disguise is more of a rubbish glasses-and-fake-moustache mask than a box, but either way it fails and he has to confront his father, eventually absconding with the game.

As it turns out, playing Sburb has the side-effect of summoning meteors towards your house. The final scene of Act 1 is John and one of his friends, Rose, racing against time to complete the setup of Sburb before the meteor hits. This is presumably the satellite crashing into his house that you remember.

Both 'weird vibe' and 'publishing more and more' are absolutely correct. Homestuck eventually spanned several thousands of pages across six acts, each more weird than the one before.

Comment: My first instinct was Homestuck as well, but I've never read it so I didn't know how well it fitted.